# Can I add a property to the current "this" object? How?

Tags: javascript, this

I am checking a this.hash property onClick of tab but onload hash doesn't exist, Can I add hash property onLoad to let this condition pass through?
So self.$("first").ready(renderPage) is called onLoad and I am trying to add this.hash to it so it passes the condition in renderPage().

```
 render : function () {
        self = this;
        renderPage = function () {
                            console.log("this.hash : " + this.hash);

                            if (this.hash) { // this.hash is only present when tab is clicked onLoad its undefined
                               //do some stuff
                                getTabClicked(this.hash);
                            }
                            buildString();

                            ajaxData.callAPI(function (data) {
                             // process data and render output;
                            });
                     }
         onloadCall = function () {
                            $(self.el).html(self.template());
                            self.$(tab).html(self.templateFlyout());
                            self.$("#allTabs").tabs().addClass("xyz");
                            self.$("#first").tabs();
                            self.$("#second").tabs();
                            //this.hash = "first"; // but it gives error this is undefined.
                            self.$("first").ready(renderPage); // I want to add this.hash before this call
                            self.$("[id^=tabs-]").click(renderPage);
                            onMenuChange();
                        },

                        readJson = function () {
                            $.getJSON("./js/data/myJson.json", function (data) {
                                jsonData = data;
                                onloadCall();
                            });
                        };

            readJson();

            return this;
        }
```

Comment: `this.myNameOfTheProperty = myValue;`

Comment: The condition shouldn't error as you are checking an undefined property not an undeclared variable. So… do nothing. (You might want to more clearly express your problem, preferably with exact error messages and enough code to reproduce the problem).

Comment: Depends on what [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is in the current call of your function.

Comment: In general yes, but we need more context. Please post the relevant part of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, easily.

```
this.newProperty = value;
// Or
this[newProperty] = value;
```

`this` is defined by the context of the current function. If you want to access the same definition of `this` outside the function it's used in, you have to know what that definition is. In your case, it looks like the definition is `document`, given that you say the context is `[#Object HTMLDocument]`. So, to add a `hash` property to that version of this is simple:

```
// instead of
this.hash = "first";
// use
document.hash = "first";
```

Comment: I added the code, have tried adding but this is undefined there.

Comment: @ArtOfCode - Do you mean `this["newProperty"] = value;` ? You can supply a string literal to name the new property, or newProperty would have to be a variable containing a valid key.

Comment: @null I was assuming newProperty as a variable but thanks for the clarification

Comment: @tumpa: what are you using this in place of? This can only be defined by giving it some context, what is your context?

Comment: @ArtOfCode - The key clarification being that if `newProperty` is a string literal, then the two lines have an identical behaviour, otherwise they are doing two different things. Subtle, but I thought it was worth bringing up. :)

Comment: I have added the code to explain the context. this is undefined in onLoadCall but its "[object HTMLDocument]" in renderpage on load though if a tab is clicked its a URL.

Comment: @ArtOfCode : Thanks that works great and then I am deleting that property right after my onload call to renderPage self.$("first").ready(renderPage) So it doesnt mess up my rest of the thing, as I call renderPage every time a dropdown is chnaged in a tab where this.hash should be undifined.

Comment: @tumpa - just set it to undefined - document.hash = undefined or this.hash = undefined;

Comment: Oh you mean that's better than deleting?

Comment: Does the same thing, either one is fine